# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar los arreglos con las funciones?

Tags: java

Es un programa para la escuela, el cual ya habíamos hecho con anterioridad pero sin funciones. Ahora debemos de realizar el mismo programa pero con funciones.
No se si este bien o vaya por buen camino.

```
public class Calificaciones
{
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        cargarValores();
    }
    public static void cargarValores()
    {
        String alumnos[] = {"Julio","Carlos","Luis","Karina","Dana","Antonio","Bryan","Jouse","Juan","David","Liliana","Gerardo","Erick"};
        int edades[]= {18,19,19,19,19,19,18,18,26,18,19,20,18};
        double estatura[]= {1.75,1.67,1.65,1.69,1.55,1.73,1.78,1.78,1.74,1.80,1.72,1.83,1.62};
        int peso[]= {78,54,55,60,65,78,95,75,81,100,70,84,72};
        int promedio=0;
        int mayor=0;
        String name = "";
        double alta=0;
        String name2 = "";
        System.out.println("\f");
        double pesom=0;
        String name3 = "";
        int suma=0;
        System.out.printf("%s%8s%10s%6s\n", "Alumnos", "Edades", "Estatura", "Peso");
        for(int i=0; i<alumnos.length; i++)
          {
              System.out.printf("%7s%8d%10.2f%6d\n", alumnos[i], edades[i], estatura[i], peso[i]);
          }

          intmayorEd = mayorEdad(edades[]);
    }
    public static int mayorEdad(int ed)
    {
        int e;
        for(int i=0; i<ed.length; i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                mayor = ed[i];

            }else if(ed[i]>mayor) 
            {
                mayor = ed[i];
            }
        }
        return e;
    }

}
```

El error me sale en esta linea:

```
intmayorEd = mayorEdad(edades[]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Algunos consideraciones y/o errores en su código

- En la línea de `intmayorEd = mayorEdad(edades[]);` hace falta un espacio para determinar el tipo y nombre de variable, es decir `int mayorEd`, además la forma de pasar el arreglo al método es incorrecto , debería ser `mayorEdad(edades);`
- Si desea utilizar variables dentro de los métodos de una clase, deben ser declaradas a nivel de clase  *(para este caso no son necesarias)*
- En el método no hace falta comparar  que el indice sea `0` si no directamente asignar a mayor `mayor = ed[0];`
- En su método retorna `e` que es un variable a nivel de método que no cambia su valor, así que técnicamente **`retornará 0 siempre`**.
- Como recomendación no declarar  variables si no se utilizarán.

**Código Final**

```
public static void main (String args []){
   cargarValores();
}
public static void cargarValores() {
    String alumnos[] = {"Julio","Carlos","Luis","Karina","Dana","Antonio","Bryan","Jouse","Juan","David","Liliana","Gerardo","Erick"};
    int edades[]= {18,19,19,19,19,19,18,18,26,18,19,20,18};
    double estatura[]= {1.75,1.67,1.65,1.69,1.55,1.73,1.78,1.78,1.74,1.80,1.72,1.83,1.62};
    int peso[]= {78,54,55,60,65,78,95,75,81,100,70,84,72};

    System.out.printf("%s%8s%10s%6s\n", "Alumnos", "Edades", "Estatura", "Peso");
    for(int i=0; i<alumnos.length; i++)
    {
       System.out.printf("%7s%8d%10.2f%6d\n", alumnos[i], edades[i], estatura[i], peso[i]);
    }
    int mayorEd = mayorEdad(edades);
    System.out.println("Mayor Edad " + mayorEd);
}
public static int mayorEdad(int[] ed)
{
    int mayor=ed[0];
    for(int i=0; i<ed.length; i++)
        if(ed[i]>mayor)  mayor = ed[i];
    return mayor;
}
```